# php how can I make sure the page is reloaded and the echo is updated to the new value

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

The users of my website can subscribe some of their animals for a competition.
My code works perfectly but there is a big issue. When a user presses subscribe the page reloads but because the isset is after the echo of the button itself the page needs to be refreshed before the buttontext changes into "subscribed".
Change the order gives issues as you probably can see.
Who can help me out? I'm out of options myself. (I translated the variables etc.)

```
<form action="" method="post" name="frmSubscribe">
<?php
$Counter = 0;
$sql = "Select * from Animals where username='".$_SESSION['User']."' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo $row['Animalname'];
    $Duiven[] = $row['AnimalID'];
    $Username[] = $row['username'];

    ?>
    <input type='submit' <?php echo "name= ".$Buttons[$Counter].""; ?> value='<?php 
    $sqlSubscribed = "SELECT * FROM Competitionresults WHERE AnimalID='".$Animals[$Counter]."'";
    $resultSubscribed = mysql_query($sqlSubscribed);
    if(mysql_num_rows($resultSubscribed) == 0){ echo "Subscribe";}
    else {echo "deregister";}
    ?>'><br/><?php
    $Teller++;
    }

if (isset($_POST['btnSubscribe1'])){

$sqlCheck = "SELECT * FROM Competitionresults WHERE AnimalID='".$Animals[0]."'";
    $resultCheck = mysql_query($sqlCheck);
    if (mysql_num_rows($resultCheck) == 0){

    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO Competitionresuls (AnimalID, username) VALUES ('".$Animals[0]."','".$Username[0]."')";
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
    ?><?php
    }
    }
```

... and so on for the next animals.

Comment: +1 for 'My code works perfectly but there is a big issue'

Comment: Ahm ok? Plz do not post useless comments. The issue is not that the code doesn't work, but that it doesn't immediately show what the code has achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use output buffering I think. Put ob_start() at the beginning of your page, now output any placeholder instead of real input code:

```
[SUMBIT]
```

instead of:

```
<input type='submit' ....
```

At the end of page you get your buffered content:

```
$content = ob_get_clean()
```

And replace submit button with correct code:

```
$content = str_replace('[SUBMIT]', 'Your actual submit button code here...', $content);
```

And now output content:

```
echo $content;
```

Answer (score 1):

quick fix can be javascript

```
echo '<span id="someid" >Subscribe</span>';
```

and when changing

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById('someid').innerHTML = 'Subscribed';</script>";
```

in future I STRONGLY suggest you to use [PHP MVC Framework](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20mvc%20framework&aq=0&oq=php%20mvc%20framework&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your post code above the page then loaded your page....
Please use like  below code:

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST['btnSubscribe1'])){

    $sqlCheck = "SELECT * FROM Competitionresults WHERE AnimalID='".$Animals[0]."'";
        $resultCheck = mysql_query($sqlCheck);
        if (mysql_num_rows($resultCheck) == 0){

            $sql1 = "INSERT INTO Competitionresuls (AnimalID, username) VALUES ('".$Animals[0]."','".$Username[0]."')";
           mysql_query($sql1);
           header('Location: samefilename.php');
           die;
         }

        }
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post" name="frmSubscribe">
    <?php
    $Counter = 0;
    $sql = "Select * from Animals where username='".$_SESSION['User']."' ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        echo $row['Animalname'];
        $Duiven[] = $row['AnimalID'];
        $Username[] = $row['username'];

        ?>
        <input type='submit' <?php echo "name= ".$Buttons[$Counter].""; ?> value='<?php 
        $sqlSubscribed = "SELECT * FROM Competitionresults WHERE AnimalID='".$Animals[$Counter]."'";
        $resultSubscribed = mysql_query($sqlSubscribed);
        if(mysql_num_rows($resultSubscribed) == 0){ echo "Subscribe";}
        else {echo "deregister";}
        ?>'><br/><?php
        $Teller++;
        }


        }
```

Comment: No, redirecting is useless now, because you load the animalws now after you did the action

Answer (score 0):

most easy solution move the `isset` up to the top. just so you know actions should always be the first things you handle after that you are gonna work on the view

```
<form action="" method="post" name="frmSubscribe">
<?php

if (isset($_POST['btnSubscribe1'])){

$sqlCheck = "SELECT * FROM Competitionresults WHERE AnimalID='".key($_GET)."'";
$resultCheck = mysql_query($sqlCheck);
if (mysql_num_rows($resultCheck) == 0){

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO Competitionresuls (AnimalID, username) VALUES ('".key($_GET)."','".$_SESSION['User']."')";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result1);

}
}

$Counter = 0;
$sql = "Select * from Animals where username='".$_SESSION['User']."' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo $row['Animalname'];
$Duiven[] = $row['AnimalID'];
$Username[] = $row['username'];

?>
<input type='submit' <?php echo "name= ".$Buttons[$Counter].""; ?> value='<?php 
$sqlSubscribed = "SELECT * FROM Competitionresults WHERE AnimalID='".$Animals[$Counter]."'";
$resultSubscribed = mysql_query($sqlSubscribed);
if(mysql_num_rows($resultSubscribed) == 0){ echo "Subscribe";}
else {echo "deregister";}
?>'><br/><?php
$Teller++;
}
```

Comment: This will not work because the information for the isset is set afterwards then, if it were that easy I would have found it myself :)

Comment: whats the problem I dont see it,

Comment: It sends empty values to the server when you place it on top, that's the problem :p

Comment: im afraid you made a big mess of your code :)  lemme edit it btw Duiven is not english... its pigeon ;)